# Accessing data in an object and creating new object with filtered data

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am trying to search for specific nodes within an object and display a new object with the required data. There could be single or multiple fields in each composite type like displayed below.

This is the original object:

```
{
  "section": "personal",
  "fields": [
    {
      "type": "composite",
      "name": "name",
      "label": "Name",
      "fields": [
        {
          "type": "text",
          "name": "given",
          "label": "First name",
          "value": "Joe"
        },
        {
          "type": "text",
          "name": "family",
          "label": "Last name",
          "value": "Smith"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "composite",
      "name": "address",
      "label": "Address",
      "fields": [
        {
          "type": "text",
          "name": "streetName",
          "label": "Street Name",
          "value": "1 High St"
        },
        {
          "type": "text",
          "name": "city",
          "label": "City",
          "value": "New York"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The resulting object should look like this:

```
{
  name: {
    given: "Joe",
    family: "Smith",
  },
  address: {
    streetName: "1 Hight St",
    city: "New York"
  }
}
```

EDIT*** Ideally, I'd like to figure out a way to use javascript methods (map/reduce/filter) and/or lodash to come up with an answer.

This is more an outline of what i've been looking at so far with built in methods.

```js
var convertVals = function() {

  var data = fields.fields;
  var filter = data.filter(function(form) {
    return form
  })
  .filter(function(form) {
    return form.name && form.fields;
  })
  .map(function(form) {
    return {form.name, [form.name.name]: form.name.value};
  })
};
convertVals();
```

Thanks,

Comment: Not certain what question is? Can you include `javascript` that you have tried to meet requirement? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi @guest271314, added some pseudocode into what I was thinking, but struggling to get it to filter down to the final level, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array.prototype.reduce()` to iterate nested `fields` arrays. Set `"name"` property value of parent object as property name of object with value set to object set to `"name"` and `"value"` properties of objects within child `"fields"` array

```js
var data = {
  "section": "personal",
  "fields": [
    {
      "type": "composite",
      "name": "name",
      "label": "Name",
      "fields": [
        {
          "type": "text",
          "name": "given",
          "label": "First name",
          "value": "Joe"
        },
        {
          "type": "text",
          "name": "family",
          "label": "Last name",
          "value": "Smith"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "composite",
      "name": "address",
      "label": "Address",
      "fields": [
        {
          "type": "text",
          "name": "streetName",
          "label": "Street Name",
          "value": "1 High St"
        },
        {
          "type": "text",
          "name": "city",
          "label": "City",
          "value": "New York"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

var res = data.fields.reduce((o, {name, fields}) => 
           (o[name] = fields.reduce((curr, {name:key, value}) =>
             (curr[key] = value, curr),{}), o), {});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, here you go! Figured I might as well take a crack at it as no more questions were coming in.

```js
var originalObject = {
  "section": "personal",
  "fields": [
    {
      "type": "composite",
      "name": "name",
      "label": "Name",
      "fields": [
        {
          "type": "text",
          "name": "given",
          "label": "First name",
          "value": "Joe"
        },
        {
          "type": "text",
          "name": "family",
          "label": "Last name",
          "value": "Smith"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "composite",
      "name": "address",
      "label": "Address",
      "fields": [
        {
          "type": "text",
          "name": "streetName",
          "label": "Street Name",
          "value": "1 High St"
        },
        {
          "type": "text",
          "name": "city",
          "label": "City",
          "value": "New York"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

function convertVals(obj){
  var retObj = {};
  for(var i=0;i<obj.fields.length;i++){
    var tempObj={};
    for(var j=0;j<obj.fields[i].fields.length;j++){
      tempObj[obj.fields[i].fields[j].name] = obj.fields[i].fields[j].value;
    }
    retObj[obj.fields[i].name] = tempObj;
  }
  return retObj;
}

console.log(convertVals(originalObject));
/*
Should return:

{
  name: {
    given: "Joe",
    family: "Smith",
  },
  address: {
    streetName: "1 Hight St",
    city: "New York"
  }
}
*/
```

Comment: Thanks, I was looking to javascript methods for a solution, but could have tried the loop.

Comment: You're welcome. I usually end up doing loops, because I have greater control over them and I don't know all of the built-in methods.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a lodash solution that uses [keyBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#keyBy) to assign the keys for each fields and [mapValues](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#keyBy) to get the value for each field.

```
function getFields(data) {
  return data.value || _(data.fields)
    .keyBy('name')
    .mapValues(getFields)
    .value();
}
```

```js
var data = {
  "section": "personal",
  "fields": [{
      "type": "composite",
      "name": "name",
      "label": "Name",
      "fields": [{
          "type": "text",
          "name": "given",
          "label": "First name",
          "value": "Joe"
        },
        {
          "type": "text",
          "name": "family",
          "label": "Last name",
          "value": "Smith"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "composite",
      "name": "address",
      "label": "Address",
      "fields": [{
          "type": "text",
          "name": "streetName",
          "label": "Street Name",
          "value": "1 High St"
        },
        {
          "type": "text",
          "name": "city",
          "label": "City",
          "value": "New York"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

function getFields(data) {
  return data.value || _(data.fields)
    .keyBy('name')
    .mapValues(getFields)
    .value();
}

console.log(getFields(data));
```

```css
body > div { min-height: 100%; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

There is a hidden implication in the solution above, if the `value` contains falsey values then it would dismiss this `value` instead and assume that there's a `fields` value. To solve this, we can use [has](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#has) to check if a `value` key exists and then perform the same operations that we did above.

```
function getFields(data) {
  return _.has(data, 'value')? data.value: 
    _(data.fields)
    .keyBy('name')
    .mapValues(getFields)
    .value();
}
```

```js
var data = {
  "section": "personal",
  "fields": [{
      "type": "composite",
      "name": "name",
      "label": "Name",
      "fields": [{
          "type": "text",
          "name": "given",
          "label": "First name",
          "value": "Joe"
        },
        {
          "type": "text",
          "name": "family",
          "label": "Last name",
          "value": "Smith"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "composite",
      "name": "address",
      "label": "Address",
      "fields": [{
          "type": "text",
          "name": "streetName",
          "label": "Street Name",
          "value": "1 High St"
        },
        {
          "type": "text",
          "name": "city",
          "label": "City",
          "value": "New York"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

function getFields(data) {
  return _.has(data, 'value')? data.value: 
    _(data.fields)
    .keyBy('name')
    .mapValues(getFields)
    .value();
}

console.log(getFields(data));
```

```css
body > div { min-height: 100%; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: Right on - thanks @ryeballar. I think the second one makes sense as it may as well!

Comment: @randomInput I edited my answer into a clean recursive approach. It's basically the same with the previous answer, I just moved the conditionals outside the `mapValues` callback.